# Is there a way to view bleed vs. workable space in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm currently working on formatting a document with a print size of 6" x 9". Certain pages include background images that extend to the edge of the page, so I've increased the page size to 6.125" x 9.25" to account for the bleed on the top, bottom, and outer edge of the pages (gutter margin doesn't require bleed space).

I'm wondering if there's a way to add some sort of temporary border around the 6" x  9" section of the page (or perhaps add color to the extra bleed space) so I can clearly see the space I need to be working with and get a better idea of the layout. I'm sure MS Publisher has a function like this, but Word is what I have to work with right now. Does anyone have any ideas?